# Can't find an element by "querySelector"

Tags: javascript, html, css

This request:

```
someTag.querySelector("tbody > tr[my-attr='333']").children
```

returns an array of "td". Some of them have an attribute "attribute1". How can I find a "td" among which has the attribute1="123"?

I've tried different approaches but hasn't been successfull. For example:

```
someTag.querySelector("tbody > tr[my-attr='333'][attribute1='123']")
```

returns null

Comment: add some samplecode... jsfiddle or the implemented source preview

Comment: If you're finding the `td`s,  `tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] td[attribute1='123']`?  Your second `tbody > tr[my-attr='333'][attribute1='123']` is finding `tr` that has `my-attr='333'` and `attribute1='123'` it has not condition check on the child `td`s.

Comment: may be `tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] > td[attribute1='123']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `querySelectorAll` to get all the `td` with `attribute1='123'`.

Check this snippets:

```js
 var tds = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] td[attribute1='123']");
 tds[0].innerHTML = "JavaScript"
 tds[1].innerHTML = "JQuery"
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr my-attr='333'>
      <td attribute1='123'>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attr='333'>
      <td attribute1='123'>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attr='333'>
      <td attribute1='124'>March</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr my-attr='333'>
      <td attribute1='124'>April</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

As per the attached sample, script as follows

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] td[attribute1='123']");
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].style.backgroundColor = '#888'
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbeg17r8/3/)**

Comment: querySelector works. But I have to put a whitespace between "td" and "[", without it, it doesn't work. I wonder why.

Comment: If you are putting space means, then the `children` of that `td` will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
var res = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] > [attribute1='123']")
console.log(res)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr my-attr="333">
      <td attribute1="123">Cell</td>
      <td attribute1="123">Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

edit: uses `querySelectorAll` because the OP wants to find multiple nodes.

Comment: but this only works for 1 element. If you have multiply td with the same attribute you will not retrive the other td's having this attribute

Comment: then use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: I know. I didnt say you answere is wrong, thats why no devote... the was simply a hint :)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one problem.

First you use `querySelector` this will cause that you will only retrive one element (the first that matches).

Use `querySelectorAll`instead.

Than you use `children`. In your sample the TD's dont have children so you will never even get one result. Even if the selector is correct. What brings me to the last point

This is the correct selector:

```
tbody > tr[my-attr='333'] > [attribute1='123']
```

Here you have a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/spxr5f7u/1/)

Comment: Even jealous devoting doesnt make the answere incorrect ;)

Comment: @JohnR never sayed so :)